# Add labels to likert scale ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add labels to a likert scale manually made plot. However, when I try to add labels, I only get some values in the right side/position, as show in the figure.  Why it's not working?

Packages:

```
   library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(scales)
```

Data example:

```
Servicos <- read.table(text="Serviços, Muito, Pouco, Nunca, NS/NR
A,.513,.328,.081, .078
B,.387,.423,.109,.081
C, .301, .384, .209, .105
D, .355, .344, .204, .097
E,  .317, .412, .191, .080
F, .092, .474, .341, .093", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


  Servicos %>%
        gather(Response, percent, -Serviços) -> likert


    likert %>%
        filter(Response=="NS.NR") %>%
        arrange(desc(percent)) %>% .$Serviços -> ind_order


    likert %>%
        mutate(Serviços=factor(Serviços, levels=ind_order, ordered=TRUE)) %>%
        mutate(Response=factor(Response,
                               levels=c("Muito", "Pouco", "Nunca", "NS.NR"), ordered=TRUE,
                               labels=c("Muito", "Pouco", "Nunca", "NS/NR"))) %>%
        mutate(percent=ifelse(Response %nin% c("Muito", "Pouco", "NS/NR"), -percent, percent)) -> lik
```

The plot:

```
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_hline(yintercept=0)
gg <- gg + geom_bar(data=filter(lik, percent<0), width=.75,
                    stat="identity", position="stack",
                    aes(x=Serviços, y=percent, fill=Response))
gg <- gg + geom_bar(data=filter(lik, percent>=0), width=.75,
                    stat="identity", position="stack",
                    aes(x=Serviços, y=percent, fill=Response))
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=filter(lik, percent<0), aes(x=Serviços, y=percent, group=Response,label = percent))
gg <- gg + scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0, .75))
gg <- gg + scale_fill_manual(values=c( "#4393c3", "#92c5de","#b2182b", "gray"),
                             drop=FALSE)
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,.10),
                              breaks=seq(-.35, 1, .25),
                              limits=c(-.35, .95),
                              labels=percent_format())
gg <- gg + coord_flip()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank()) 
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
gg
```

[image]

Comment: Which text exactly do you want to be included on the plot?

Comment: As by `geom_text`, I would like to show percent values, see `(label = percent)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon mpalanco's partially answer, you can work around of this using two different lines for `geom_text`:

`gg <- gg + geom_text(data=filter(lik, percent<0), aes(x=Serviços, y = percent, group=Response,label = paste(percent*100, "%")), position = "stack", hjust = -.2,  size = 2.5, color="white")`

`gg <- gg + geom_text(data=filter(lik, percent>0), aes(x=Serviços, y = percent, group=Response,label = paste(percent*100, "%")), position = "stack", hjust = 1, size = 2.5)`

[image]

Comment: Sounds much better, but I rather like value labels centered in each chunk of the bar. If I dived the y by 2, it gets really messy.

Answer (score 0):

To show percent values add `label = paste(percent*100, "%")` in the line:

```
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=filter(lik, percent<0), aes(x=Serviços, y=percent, group=Response,label = paste(percent*100, "%")))
```

[image]

Comment: The thing with your answer is that it shows only part of the numbers, where are the labels for the blue bars? In other words, your answer produces the very same result that I uploaded, just changed from proportion to percentage.

Comment: I got around this on one of my plots by adding a column to the data that contains the percent values, then plotting that as text.  So perhaps you can add a column that gives you the percent of each Response for each Servicos, then plot that.  I'll try it when I have some time today.

Comment: Just to clarify, I can easily plot values for the other side of the bars by not filtering the data:  `geom_text(data=lik, aes(x=Serviços, y=percent, group=Response,label = paste(percent*100, "%")))` the thing is that the numbers mess up.